# Setting a session variable via function

Tags: javascript, session, global-variables

I've scratched my head for an hour at this basic task. I'm slowly building up a google api lookup which triggers a google map on a seperate page. I want to pass the initial search text (via a textbox) to the map page via a session (which i think is the best way to do it?)
However the function just wont set the session variable. Why can't i even set it to "yes" via the below function?

```
<script>
function secondFunction()   {
alert("pressed");
$_SESSION[$var] = "yes";
 }
```

Comment: Because JavaScript !== PHP ?  `$_SESSION` is a PHP feature. PHP is executed on the **server**, JavaScript on the **client**.

Comment: @FelixKling: Hm, don't we have a canonical duplicate target that is reverse to [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23740548/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/218196 maybe?

Comment: I had skimmed the previous questions but couldnt work through the answer. I think i am taking the wrong approach in: 
taking text via PHP to new page

I will instead use form functions.